# Django get a QuerySet from array of id's in specific order

Tags: django, arrays

heres a quick one for you:

I have a list of id's which I want to use to return a QuerySet(or array if need be), but I want to maintain that order.

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I don't think you can enforce that particular order on the database level, so you need to do it in python instead.

```
id_list = [1, 5, 7]
objects = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)

objects = dict([(obj.id, obj) for obj in objects])
sorted_objects = [objects[id] for id in id_list]
```

This builds up a dictionary of the objects with their id as key, so they can be retrieved easily when building up the sorted list.

Comment: I was hoping that this wasn't the case :( thanks for the clean code!

Comment: Just beware of huge queries as you'll be storing the result in memory when doing this.

Comment: Maybe use the querysets in_bulk() method, rather than constructing the dictionary yourself?

Comment: The problem with this is if an object in the id_list doesn't exist it will throw an error.

Comment: Why not use dict comprehension?

Comment: Can do 
    objects = {
        obj.id: obj for obj in Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
    }
    sorted_objects = [objects[id] for id in id_list]

Answer (score 298):

Since Django 1.8, you can do:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

pk_list = [10, 2, 1]
preserved = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).order_by(preserved)
```

Comment: Best answer because it actually returns a queryset

Comment: I still think that django's `Case` `When` are underrated!

Comment: I'm going to use `distinct()` with order_by case when clause but got the error. any support, please.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions` - here is the error message

Comment: I strongly recommend this is the best answer!

Comment: great answer. I really wanted a solution that returns a queryset and found this answer after a long search. Brilliant @Soitje

Comment: How to do a descending on preserved as in my case pk_list is a list of strings like ['Python', 'PHP', 'Java', '.Net', 'Nodejs']  and so preserved becomes: preserved = Case(*[When(agent_type=agent_type, then=pos) for pos, agent_type in enumerate(od)]) and as a result theses ordered value ends up being in last

Comment: is it optimized for pagination also? meaning does it process all the results(I want to use `Paginator`, hence do not want all the results to be fetched)?

Comment: What happens when there's no object with a given ID? What should I do if I want an error? What should I do if I just want `None`?

Comment: This should have been the selected answer.

Comment: This should not be the selected answer, at least should not go without a warning about the performance. This way it does not perform well, neither on small querysets nor on big ones. sorting the result using plain python list, as in other answers performs much faster and should be considered on small QSs. On big ones you can't do it this way at all.

Comment: My hero <3. I've spent many hours at last few days searching for a solution like this.

Comment: This is the perfect one.

Comment: This is the best answer as it is returning query set. Big thank you

Answer (score 30):

If you want to do this using in_bulk, you actually need to merge the two answers above:

```
id_list = [1, 5, 7]
objects = Foo.objects.in_bulk(id_list)
sorted_objects = [objects[id] for id in id_list]
```

Otherwise the result will be a dictionary rather than a specifically ordered list.

Comment: This is not a better answer.

Answer (score 30):

Here's a way to do it at database level. Copy paste from: [blog.mathieu-leplatre.info](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html)
 :

**MySQL**:

```
SELECT *
FROM theme
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 10, 2, 1);
```

Same with Django:

```
pk_list = [10, 2, 1]
ordering = 'FIELD(`id`, %s)' % ','.join(str(id) for id in pk_list)
queryset = Theme.objects.filter(pk__in=[pk_list]).extra(
           select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
```

**PostgreSQL**:

```
SELECT *
FROM theme
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN id=10 THEN 0
    WHEN id=2 THEN 1
    WHEN id=1 THEN 2
  END;
```

Same with Django:

```
pk_list = [10, 2, 1]
clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
queryset = Theme.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra(
           select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Failed for me : django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: FIELD :(

Answer (score 13):

```
id_list = [1, 5, 7]
objects = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
sorted(objects, key=lambda i: id_list.index(i.pk))
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining how this works and why it would solve the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works well, could use additional information though

Comment: this will work only for ordered idlist. Can you confirm if it will work of any sequence... seems not true to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another better/cleaner approach can be

```
pk_list = [10, 2, 1]
sorted_key_object_pair = MyModel.objects.in_bulk(pk_list)
sorted_objects = sorted_key_object_pair.values()
```

Simple, clean, less code.

Comment: Alright, provided you don't need a QuerySet.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem on PostgreSQL using [`array_position`](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/array_position/)

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, IntegerField, OrderBy
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


class ArrayPosition(Func):
    function = "array_position"

    def __init__(self, items, field):
        super().__init__(items, field, output_field=IntegerField(null=True))


pk_list = [10, 2, 1]

queryset = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    pk_order=ArrayPosition(pk_list, Cast("pk", IntegerField()))
).order_by(OrderBy(F("pk_order"), nulls_last=True))
```

I generates smaller SQL unlike Case/When solution (when there are lot of items).

```sql
SELECT
    ...,
    array_position(ARRAY[10, 4, 1], ("my_model"."id")::integer) AS "pk_order"
FROM "my_model"
ORDER BY pk_order ASC NULLS LAST
```

vs.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM "my_model"
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN "my_model"."id" = 10 THEN 0
    WHEN "my_model"."id" = 4 THEN 1
    WHEN "my_model"."id" = 1 THEN 2
    ELSE NULL END ASC
```