# Django: Grab a set of objects from ID list (and sort by timestamp)

Tags: python, database, django, model, django-queryset

I have a list of IDs for objects that I need to grab, then I have to sort them by their timestamp. Here's how I was going to do it:

```
For i in object_ids:
  instance = Model.objects.get(id = i)
  # Append instance to list of instances 

#sort the instances list
```

But there are two things that bother me:

- Is there no way to grab a collection of entries by a list of their IDs - without having to loop?
- Can I append arbitrary objects to the QuerySet just based on their IDs ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This can be done using such a code:

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(id__in=object_ids).order_by('-timestamp')
```

the `order_by` can be positive or negative `timestamp`, depending how you want it sorted.

Comment: What's the nicest way to get the objects returned in the same order as the object_ids list? The OPs code?

Comment: I would probably fetch the data from the database with only one call (such as above) and then make the sorting in your code. Should be faster then querying the database N times. Especially with a large N.

Comment: @kender @Chris Do we have any solution for `in the same order as the object_ids list` rather than sorting after fetching?

Comment: @Dipak I retrieved them as in @kendor's answer, put them in a `dict` `id->object`, then iterated `object_ids` for the key. I didn't test the performance as it wasn't critical.

Comment: @Dipak I found a brilliant answer that returns a queryset here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648265/1526703

Answer (score 10):

Try the following:

```
result = Model.objects.filter(id__in=object_ids)
```

This returns all `Model` objects that have their `id` in the given list of `object_ids`. This way, you also don't need to append additional models to the resulting QuerySet.