# How to sort a Django QuerySet by (field, custom function, field)

Tags: python, django

I am looking for getting a QuerySet that is sorted by field1, function, field2.

The model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    issue_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    priority_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def due_date(self):
        ...
        return ageing
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
taskList = Task.objects.all().order_by('priority_id', ***duedate***, 'title')
```

Obviously, you can't sort a queryset by custom function. Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the actual sorting happens in the database, which does not speak Python, you cannot use a Python function for ordering. You will need to implement your due date logic in an SQL expression, as an [`Queryset.extra(select={...})`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra) calculated field, something along the lines of:

```
due_date_expr = '(implementation of your logic in SQL)'
taskList = Task.objects.all().extra(select={'due_date': due_date_expr}).order_by('priority_id', 'due_date', 'title')
```

If your logic is too complicated, you might need to implement it as a stored procedure in your database.

Alternatively, if your data set is *very* small (say, tens to a few hundred records), you can fetch the entire result set in a list and sort it post-factum:

```
taskList = list(Task.objects.all())
taskList.sort(cmp=comparison_function) // or .sort(key=key_function)
```

Comment: Nice answer. So it should either be dealt with in SQL end or in Python end.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @lanzz, even though seems correct, didn't work for me but this answer from another thread did the magic for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648265/6420686

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

ids = [list of ids]
preserved = Case(*[When(id=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(ids)])
filtered_users = User.objects \
    .filter(id__in=ids) \
    .order_by(preserved)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort in Python if the queryset is not too large:

```
ordered = sorted(Task.objects.all(), key=lambda o: (o.priority_id, o.due_date(), o.title))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but will this not become a order_by(duedate, title) -- without priority_id ?