# Django : Conditional expressions in get_queryset(self)

Tags: python, django, django-views, conditional-statements

I am in Django 1.11 and I would like to combine what I read:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q

For example, suppose I have something like this that will check if Objects are in the user area and a ListView use it.

```
    open_help_requests = HelpRequest.objects.filter(state=HelpRequest.OPEN)
    filtered_help_requests = []
    for help_request in open_help_requests:
        """ Formule de Haversine pour connaitre la distance entre deux points géographiques """
        earth_radius = 6373.0

        lat1 = radians(help_request.student.studentcollaborator.postal_code.latitude)
        lon1 = radians(help_request.student.studentcollaborator.postal_code.longitude)
        lat2 = radians(request.user.student.studentcollaborator.postal_code.latitude)
        lon2 = radians(request.user.student.studentcollaborator.postal_code.longitude)

        dlon = lon2 - lon1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1

        a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

        distance = earth_radius * c
        if distance <= help_request.settings.distance:
            filtered_help_requests.append(help_request)
```

What I want to move this condition check inside the **filter** in **def get_queryset(self):** so that I could directly make additional simple order/filter operations with the filtered QuerySet. Recreate the QuerySet with the filtered variable list id looks too heavy (like this : [Django get a QuerySet from array of id's in specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916851/django-get-a-queryset-from-array-of-ids-in-specific-order/4916892#4916892)).

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quite not sure that I'm understanding you well.
Anyway,what about creating custom `models.QuerySet` for your models `models.Manager`?

Inside your custom `models.QuerySet` you can create your own functions for your ordering/filtering goals.

And in your view you can directly get your filtered/ordered list of your objects.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ....
    objects = FooManager()
    ....

class FooManager(models.Manager):
    ....
    def get_queryset(self):
        return FooQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    ....

class FooQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    ....
    # define your functions here
    # just a simple example
    def order(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(
            # you may use Q objects here or whatever 
            ).distinct()
        else:
           return self
    ....
```

And in your view:

```
class BarView(ListView):
    ....
    def get_queryset(self):
        ....
        return Foo.objects.all().order(params) # your custom function
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer : the problem is I just want to filter based on the result (append part) and do another filters . Recreate the queryset at each step is heavy