# In a Queryset use order_by the order that pks/ids are found in an ArrayField

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with an ArrayField:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    path = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), blank=True, null=True)
```

The path values, for example:

```
{19,21, 34, 22}
```

I get all Item Objects which ids are in another Item path:

```
qs = Item.filter(id__in=item.path)
```

I need to get the elements, in the order that are in the path(not taking in consideration the values in the Array).

Using `order_by('path')` gives 'strange' results, because I suspect is taking in consideration all `paths` and not the order of the elements in a specific path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As by the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), it should rather be `order_by('path')`.

Comment: thanks, that was a typing mistake, but the suggested answer gives wrong results, because is taking in consideration all paths and not the order of the elements in the path

Comment: Oh, I get that now, [this thread's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648265/1557013) might be what you've been looking for.