# Count and group by foreign key and return model django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

### Data Model:

- Each `Library` has many `Book`s
- Each `Book` may or may not be read by a `User` dictated by the `UserBookReceipt`

### Objective:

Given a user, order the libraries by how many books they have read at each library.

### Example:

User 1 has read:

- 2 Books from Library 1
- 5 Books from Library 2
- 1 Book from Library 3
- 0 Books from Library 4

We should return the libraries in order of number of books read by User 1 ie:

```
Library 2, Library 1, Library 3
```

### Current solution

```
libraries = (UserBookReceipt.objects
    .filter(user=user)
    .values('book__library')
    .annotate(rcount=Count('book__library'))
    .order_by('-rcount')
)
```

### Actual output

```
[
    {'book_library': 2, 'rcount': 5}, 
    {'book_library': 1, 'rcount': 2}, 
    {'book_library': 3, 'rcount': 1}
]
```

### Expected output

```
[
    {'book_library': <Library: 2>, 'rcount': 5}, 
    {'book_library': <Library: 1>, 'rcount': 2}, 
    {'book_library': <Library: 3>, 'rcount': 1}
]
```

The actual output is 90% of what I want, except I want the `book_library` value to be instances of the django `Library` model rather than just the library id. Otherwise, I have to make another query to retrieve the `Library` objects which would probably require some inefficient [`ids__in` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648265/1376627).

How can I count and group by the `UserBookReceipt.book__library` and return the Library model?

If I were to do this in SQL the query would look like

```
with rcount_per_lib as (
    select lib.id, count(*) as rcount
    from lib, books, user_book_receipts
    where user_book_receipts.book_id = books.id
        and lib.id = books.lib_id 
        and user_book_receipts.user_id = 1
    group by lib.id)
select lib.*, rcount from rcount_per_lib 
where lib.id = rcount_per_lib.id 
order by rcount
```

Comment: If you are going to use SQL, you should really to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Why? AFAIK the `and` syntax is equivalent performance wise to `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change how you approach the queryset. Use `Library` rather than `UserBookReceipt`.

```
libraries = (Library.objects
    .filter(book__userbookreceipt__user=user)
    .annotate(rcount=Count('book__userbookreceipt', distinct=True))
    .order_by('-rcount')
)
[x.rcount for x in libraries]
```