# Django performant way to get a queryset of a massive (I'm talking huge) list of ids in order

Tags: python, sql, django

Pretty much the same flavor as: [Django get a QuerySet from array of id's in specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916851/django-get-a-queryset-from-array-of-ids-in-specific-order). I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648265/4810639

But my list of ids is huge (> 50000) and both `qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)` and `qs = qs.order_by(preserved)` buckle under the strain.

Note: I need a queryset due to the specific django method I'm overriding so anything returning a list won't work.

**EDIT:** In response to the comments I'm specifically overriding the `get_search_results()` in the admin. My search engine returns the `id` of the model(s) that match the query. But `get_search_results()` needs to return a queryset. Hence the large list of `id`'s.

Comment: I would use pagination

Comment: Why do you have a list of 50,000 IDs in the first place? This could well be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: @Jason could you give a bit more info on that?

Comment: @Chris please see the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by creating a `FakeQueryset` class that had enough of the functions of a regular queryset that it was able to act like one. Then when I needed to display it I would hand it over to a custom paginator that would only pull a few `id`s from the database at a time. Duck typing for the win!